# SPARQL endpoints and GraphDB

Tags: sparql, endpoint, wikidata, graphdb, federated-queries

I am a student and I'm learning to use sparql. I would like to query an endpoint by running the sparql query from GRAPHDB. 
So looking online I found that the solution is to use SERVICE with the endpoint link.

I have tried with the wikidata endpoint on GRAPHDB but the query result is empty.

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>

SELECT DISTINCT
?partyLabel
WHERE {
     SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/namespace/categories/sparql> { 
      ?party wdt:P31 wd:Q7278;
              wdt:P17 wd:Q38.

      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
      }
}
LIMIT 5
```

However, the same query (without SERVICE) works on https://query.wikidata.org.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
?partyLabel
WHERE { 
      ?party wdt:P31 wd:Q7278;
              wdt:P17 wd:Q38.

      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
LIMIT 5
```

Surely I didn't understand how SERVICE works or something else, could you help me out? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: why do you use `https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/namespace/categories/sparql` instead of `https://query.wikidata.org/sparql` ?

Comment: I found it here [link](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual/SPARQL_Federation_endpoints)

Comment: well, this list contains endpoints which you can query from the public Wikidata endpoint. But you want to query the public Wikidata from your own SPARQL endpoint, or not? IF so, use the other URL I provided

Comment: or do you use the public wikidata endpoint? I mean, this is indeed empty because it just contains category data? Your second query is correct as it queries all the Wikidata facts

Comment: ok, I tried on graphdb with the link you provided me, but it doesn't work. the result is empty

Comment: the issue is with the nested SERVICE clause, this fails here. Do `PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
SELECT DISTINCT
?partyLabel
WHERE {
     SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> {
      ?party wdt:P31 wd:Q7278;
wdt:P17 wd:Q38.
?party <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?partyLabel . filter(lang(?partyLabel) = "en")

      }
}
LIMIT 5` instead

Comment: You solved my problem, thank you very much